# Maximum number of iterations to train a neural network

Tags: neural-network, data-mining

I have a set of size N. How can I determine whether this data set is trained or not?

Training will take place infinitely if the data I feed is random. So I should have a maximum number iterations for which a neural network can be considered as trained normally, to avoid having an infinite number of iterations.

What is the maximum number of iteration for which I can consider the Neural Network as trained?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to define a confidence interval, which you are ready to accept. Please read the article: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=00478409 for further information.